# VBA code to add current date in next cell

Tags: vba, excel, date, macros

[image]I have below data (attached), which I have to add manually everyday.
Now, I am trying to automate it.

1. I would want to add current date in the next cell available (Ex : Cell E1)
2. Second cell (E2), should get the return value of rows visible after autofilter from another Sheet named "Stock".

[image]

Please help me with these two codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub main()
    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(2, 1) = Application.Transpose(Array(Date, Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, Worksheets("Stock").UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible))))
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Unfortunately, I am getting an count as zero. I have inserted module and placed the code and I have a button on Sheet2 and when i click on button date gets added but the count on E2 is zero. Where as on Sheet1 named "Stock" has 60 rows..

Comment: add screenshot of "Stock" data at the moment the counting takes place

Comment: Please do find the sample data screen shot

Comment: I wouldn't say why you get a 0 count. I tested it without any problem. just check sheet names and be sure that worksheet "Stock" actually has _visible_ rows. You may also place a breakpoint at line `.Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(2, 1) = ...` and once you get there query Immediate Window typing  `?Worksheets("Stock").UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).Address` and pressing return to see what address it displays

Comment: Awesome!! thank you. Sheet-name was the culprit here!! dint notice (!) in it.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? How do I select the previous ten days data from current date entry. Example :As per my first screenshot Lets say i get the today entry will be on Column E and I want to select previous 10 entries to create a graph. So, if I come tomo, my entry will be on F and I want to select column F,E,D,C,,,,

Comment: You are welcome. As per this site rules new issues must be posted with new questions. Since I fulfilled your _original_ question please mark answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123061/discussion-between-sady-and-user3598756).