# VBA code to auto select previous 10 columns

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Referring from my previous question.

[VBA code to add current date in next cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425337/vba-code-to-add-current-date-in-next-cell)[image]

How do I select the previous ten days data from current date entry. Example :As per my first screenshot Lets say i get the today entry will be on Column E and I want to select previous 10 entries to create a graph. So, if I come tomo, my entry will be on F and I want to select column F,E,D,C,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping you previous code from link, try this (untested):

**edited** after OPs clarifications

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update()
    Dim nCols As Long, nOffset As Long

    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        With .Offset(, .Columns.Count - 1).Resize(1, 1)
            If .value < Date Then nOffset = 1
            With .Offset(, nOffset)
                .Resize(2, 1).value = Application.Transpose(Array(Date, Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, Worksheets("Stock").UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible))))
                nCols = IIf(.Column > 10, 10, 10 - .Column - 1)
                .Offset(, -nCols + 1).Resize(, nCols).Select
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Code works a treat!! But concern, since we are using previous code in the same function. When ever I click button it keeps adding date and count data. So the selection of 10 previous data will omit the last entry.

Comment: Can we add a condition so that date and count of visible rows will be added once per day? So that selection columns will work as expected.

Comment: You are just amazing!! take a bow!! Thanks a ton!!

Comment: I know I am little late. But I have small question. Your code works great, small concern is its selecting 10 columns as required but its selecting only the first row. I tried to modify the code to select 2,3 and 4 row(screenshot) as well but I failed to do..How do I add the same in your code? Would you like me to post an other question?

Comment: As per this site rules you have to post a new question, posting your code attempts and detailing what actually doesn't work . And I'll answer that you have to use `.Offset(, -nCols + 1).Resize(3, nCols).Select` ...

Comment: Thank you, surely I will post a new question as I had an other concern