# VBA code to get the return value of visible rows

Tags: vba, excel, macros

[image]

[image]Referring from my previous question.

[VBA code to auto select previous 10 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426748/vba-code-to-auto-select-previous-10-columns)

I am trying to add the return value of visible rows from an other sheet. I tried to modify the code given in that post and I am certainly doing something wrong here as its overwriting values entered from the above line of code.

```
Sub Update()
    Dim nCols As Long, nOffset As Long, Srce As Range

    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        With .Offset(, .Columns.Count - 1).Resize(1, 1)
            If .Value < Date Then nOffset = 1
            With .Offset(, nOffset)
                .Resize(2, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Array(Date, Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, Worksheets("Stock").UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible))))
               nCols = IIf(.Column > 10, 10, 10 - .Column - 1)
              .Offset(, -nCols + 1).Resize(, nCols).Select
             End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I tried to add the below line to get the return values of visible rows

```
.Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(3, 1) = Application.Subtotal(103, Sheets("Sharedstocks").Range("A:A"))
```

Please suggest

Comment: please add some screenshots/data to clarify input and desired output

Comment: @user3598756, using same screenshot, I have bunch of data on Sheets "Stock" (first screenshot) and "SharedStock". I would like to add the count of visible rows on third sheet In the above example if you see, I need to add current date (E1) and return value of "Stock" on E2 and Return value of "SharedStock" on E3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this is what you are after:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update()
    Dim nCols As Long, nOffset As Long, Srce As Range

    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        With .Offset(, .Columns.Count - 1).Resize(1, 1)
            If .Value < Date Then nOffset = 1
            With .Offset(, nOffset)
                .Resize(3, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Array(Date, _
                                                                  Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, Worksheets("Stock").UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible)), _
                                                                  Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, Worksheets("SharedStock").UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible)) _
                                                                  ) _
                                                            )
               nCols = IIf(.Column > 10, 10, 10 - .Column - 1)
              .Offset(, -nCols + 1).Resize(, nCols).Select
             End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```